# git stash apply not working - merge conflicts

Tags: git

I'm trying to do a git stash apply and am getting errors about merge conflicts.  Every time I fix the merge conflicts and commit my changes, though, and then try to apply the stash again, I get the same merge conflict errors.  How can I fix this?  I had changes that I worked on for several hours in that stash!

This is what it looks like:

```
$ git stash apply
Auto-merging Gemfile.lock
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Gemfile.lock
Auto-merging Gemfile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Gemfile
$
```

After fixing merge and committing, I still get the same merge conflicts!

Can I force a git stash apply??

Comment: You can't force a git stash apply, as it doesn't know how to auto merge those files. See this article http://stefaanlippens.net/resolve-git-unmerged-paths-after-stash-pop

Comment: I tried a git reset --hard but it still gives me a merge conflict every time I try to do the stash pop afterward.

Comment: So you are trying to apply changes from one stash, after merge conflicts occurs you resolve them and then finish the merge with commit. What stash you are trying to apply later the different one ? with other changes ? Because I don't fully understand what are you trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the last stash was actually a stash in a different branch I had been working on.  When I applied the right stash (with git stash apply stash@{1}), it worked correctly.

Comment: git doesn't remove a stash during apply if it had errors. You need to remove it manually after fixing the conflicts and committing.

Answer (score -1):

I to had the same problem. I did the following change which solved me.
By default in server it will be pointed to Master branch. I created a new branch and deployed my code which solved me the issue. I don't want to mean that this the correct solution. But this solved me the problem.